# SailsJS (v0.9.16) + MySQL -- Accessing Models From Controllers

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I just started with Node.js using Sails.js MVC and I am having problems understanding the MVC structure within Sails.  I come from a PHP background and have extensively used Laravel, Zend, and CodeIgniter, but now I am trying to learn a whole new language alongside a whole new MVC.

**Threads Model**

```
var Threads = {
    tableName: 'threads',
    adapter: 'mysql',
    attributes: {

    ThreadID: 'INTEGER',
    ThreadPosition: 'INTEGER',
    ThreadTitle: {
        type: 'STRING',
        max: 150,
        required: true
    },
    ThreadContent: {
        type: 'STRING',
        required: true
    },
    PosterUserID: 'INTEGER',
    PosterUsername: 'STRING',
    ThreadCreationDate: 'DATETIME',
    IsClosed: 'INTEGER',
    IsDeleted: 'INTEGER'
    }
};

module.exports = Threads;
```

**Threads Controller**

```
var threaderController = {
    index: function(req,res) {

        Threads.findAll.exec(function (err, threads){
           console.log(threads);
        });
    }
};
module.exports = threaderController;
```

When I try to access the 'Threads' Model, Sails errors out and says that the 'Threads' variable does not exist.

I know I am missing something similar.  I have thoroughly looked through the Sails documentation, but it is really not that informative in this given area.

Thanks for the assistance in advance!